# Comando de busqueda find por minutos no me funciona en solaris

Tags: linux, find, solaris

El siguiente comando que me funciona en linux, no me funciona en solaris

```
[root@maquinasolaris ~]$ [ -z $(find /data/transaction -type f -mmin +60) ] && echo "false" || echo "true"
find: bad option -mmin
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
false
```

He probado también con -cmin con idéntico resultado.

Comment: Es porque en Solaris no estás usando GNU find. ¿Has intentado instalarlo?

Comment: Pues no tengo permisos de instalación en la maquina, tendría que pedir la instalación, no se cual será el comando para instalar. Gracias de nuevo @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'